# Pegar atributo dentro de um array no MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Olá, amigos. Boa noite!
Estou tendo um problema no desenvolvimento de uma api, preciso fazer a consulta de alguns atributos dentro de um array de um Schema no MongoDB para adicioná-los à um e-mail de um pedido.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? segue abaixo o modelo do Schema:

Eu preciso pegar os valores do array 'items', porém só preciso de price, quantity e title.

```js
const schema = new Schema({
    customer: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Customer'
    },
    email: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: false,
        ref: 'Customer'
    },
    name: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: false,
        ref: 'Customer'
    },
    number: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    createDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['created', 'done'],
        default: 'created'
    },
    items: [{
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        price: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        product: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Product'
        },        
        title: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
            ref: 'Product'
        }
    }],
});
```

Comment: Já deu uma olhada nesse [recurso](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/) para *Query* em *arrays*?

Comment: Qual é a dúvida mais especificamente? O que já tentou?

Answer (score 1):

Você quer aplicar um filtro que pegue apenas esses três campos dentro de items certo. O `findOne(conditions, [fields], [options], [callback])` ou sem `callback` com `async/await`. Ficaria assim.

> Com async/await:

```
const { items } = await Products.findOne({_id: 'objectId' },'items.price items.quantity items.title')
consolelog(items[0])
res.status(200).send(items[0])
```

Resultado da busca com async:

```
{
    "quantity": "",
    "price": "",
    "title": ""
}
```

> Sem async e com callback:

```
Products.findOne({_id: 'objectId'},'items.price items.quantity items.title', (err, result) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log(result.items[0])
        res.status(200).send(result.items[0])
    }
})
```

Resultado da variável `result` com uma lista dentro do objeto:

```
{
    "quantity": "",
    "price": "",
    "title": ""
}
```

No primeiro resultado eu usei desestruturação  para pegar apenas items, no segundo resultado com callback fica mais complicado mas nada que dificulte muito.